# How I can connect 2 postgres dbs to my app?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js, nestjs, objection.js

So my question described in topic. I have 2 postgres dbs hosted by docker and service with Nest.js. Also I use knex + objection.js. I spent about 2 hours searching this on google and found nothing compared to my stack

For now I connect 1 db like this:

```
const customProviders = [
 {
   provide: 'KnexConnection',
   useFactory: async (config: Config) => {
     const connection = knex(config.db);
     await connection.migrate.latest();
     Model.knex(connection);
     return connection;
   },
   inject: [Config]
 }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 separate `knex` instances. One for connecting each database.

You can then choose for every query to which database query should be sent with `Model.query(dbConnection)...` or you can create 2 sets of models, which are bound to different databases with https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/static-methods.html#static-bindknex.

Basically you can do

```
const PersonBoundToDb1 = Person.bindKnex(db1);
const PersonBoundToDb2 = Person.bindKnex(db2);

// this query goes to db1
await PersonBoundToDb1.query()...;

// this query goes to db2
await PersonBoundToDb2.query()...;
```

More info how to use multitenant databases with objection.js is found here https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/recipes/multitenancy-using-multiple-databases.html#model-binding-pattern